"Geometry error: One or more input features have invalid geometry." error when polygonizing in QGIS
How do I fix this raster that I aim to polygonize via QGIS?
For context, the raster is created from DEM STRM data. I tried to check whether the reclassification is the issue but the general log message still says:

Geometry error: One or more input features have invalid geometry.



Regarding the QGIS Polygonize tool, my raster layer doesnt show in the choices on the dropdown menu, probably because QGIS polygonize tool is under vector based on the processing toolbox

By the timestamps the geometry errors are not from your process. The gdal_polygonize error is that "NoneType object has no attribute CreateLayer". I would place the input and output files to use simple paths like c:\input and c:\output, and rename them with simple names. Spaces in filenames tend to make troubles.
